# Change user agent with selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
xpaths = { 'video' :   "//video[@id='video']",
     }

from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;     Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0   Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()
baseurl = "XXXX"
mydriver.get(baseurl)
```

---

It's not changing the user agent. I want the user agent to be chrome. I don't know what's wrong...

And also, here's what i'd like it to do: Go to the website, if it redirects to another url > Goes back to main page and keeps doing that until it finds (id:video)
I have not implemented this yet because i have no idea how to...
The website i'm trying to automate got a vid and it appears sometimes. What i'd like this to do is keep visiting the website until it finds the id:video clicks it and waits.

Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are navigating to your application URL using the wrong firefox instance - `mydriver`. Using the correct firefox instance (with required profile setting) should do the work (which is `driver` in your case).

Below is the correct code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
xpaths = { 'video' :   "//video[@id='video']",
     }

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;     Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0   Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

# the below line is not required
#mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()
baseurl = "XXXX" 

# navigate to url with 'driver' instead of 'mydriver'
driver.get(baseurl)
```

If you change your `baseurl` to "http://whatsmyuseragent.com/", you will be able to right away see if the user agent change is reflected correctly.

Hope this helps!